# Extract a specific *.zip within a *.zip file to a certain directory

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I have multiple `SHAPE_*.zip` files in a directory, and within each of these .zip files there is another zip file named `AREA_IMOVEL.zip`. I want to extract the content of this file in a folder with the name of the parent .zip file.

```bash
RR/SHAPE_143017.zip
                =======> AREA_IMOVEL.zip
RR/SHAPE_143083.zip
                =======> AREA_IMOVEL.zip
DB/SHAPE_123478.zip
                =======> AREA_IMOVEL.zip
AF/SHAPE_134797.zip
                =======> AREA_IMOVEL.zip
```

I want to extract them as below:

```
RR/SHAPE_143017/AREA_IMOVEL.shp & other files
RR/SHAPE_143083/AREA_IMOVEL.shp & other files
DB/SHAPE_123478/AREA_IMOVEL.shp & other files
AF/SHAPE_134797/AREA_IMOVEL.zip & other files
```

I use the following to get nearly similar results.

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {} \;
find . -name 'AREA_IMOVEL.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {} \;
find . \! -name 'AREA_IMOVEL.*' -delete
```

Comment: Does the first answer in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518370/extract-several-zip-files-each-in-a-new-folder-with-the-same-name-via-ubuntu-t) help?

Comment: Thanks, @philiptomk. The thread helped a lot. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
ai_zip=AREA_IMOVEL.zip
find . -name '*.zip' | while read top_zip; do
    dir=${top_zip%.zip}
    mkdir -p "$dir"                          || exit 2
    # extract only $ai_zip from $top_zip
    unzip -d "$dir" "$top_zip"     "$ai_zip" || exit 3
    # now unzip $ai_zip itself
    unzip -d "$dir" "$dir/$ai_zip"           || exit 4
    rm "$dir/$ai_zip"
done
```